# I have answered 2 questions with a score of 1 each on the tag digital-logic. Yet my tag score is only 1 for digital-logic. Why?

Tags: support

My tag score for [digital-logic] is 1 instead of 2. Why?

Comment: Is that a binary question? (Lol)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tag scores are updated once every 24 hours. You got two upvotes the last hour, but it may take a while for your tag score to be updated.